# Get client's IP address in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an micro services application in asp.net core 2.2. I want to fetch out the IP address of the user from where he is using it.

The below snippet provides the ip address of the hosted server.

```
var remoteIpAddress = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

I want to get the ip address of the user who is using the APIs for audit log purpose.

Comment: i think you'll have to pass that thru to the server (web api) from the client

Comment: If you are hosting the web api and calling the web api on the same machine then you will see the same IP address with `request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`.

Comment: @JohnB Can you please provide me the steps or example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject `IHttpContextAccessor`

And put the below snippet

```
var result = string.Empty;

 //first try to get IP address from the forwarded header
                if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers != null)
                {
                    //the X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header field is a de facto standard for identifying the originating IP address of a client
                    //connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer

                    var forwardedHeader = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
                    if (!StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(forwardedHeader))
                        result = forwardedHeader.FirstOrDefault();
                }

                //if this header not exists try get connection remote IP address
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
                    result = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

I think it may work.